# Error in plotting line and bar chart together in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Can anyone help me in plotting the line chart correctly. I am new to d3.js and cannot find the problem in the graph which I have created.

The Line is not coming in correct coordinates.

I have created a JSfiddle: `<https://jsfiddle.net/sunshine1987/q632x6dt/4/>`

Comment: I don't find any issues please clarify what is breaking or what is desired.

Comment: Sunshine, would you mind adding some code into this post? Using backticks for URLs to subvert the requirement for code to accompany pasteboards is not really in the spirit of this site's guidelines.